# Is there a file with every color on Python?

Tags: python, colors, pygame

I am working on several Pygame projects, although it is inconvenient to copy and paste a few colors that I made from a previous file into the one I am working on next. I was wondering if there is code I can make into a file I import or code I can download that has all (or most) of the colors in python that work in Pygame. Thanks!

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((600,600)) 

pygame.display.set_caption("plz help")

white=(255,255,255)#r,g,b
black=(0,0,0)
red=(255,0,0)
green=(0,255,0)
blue=(0,0,255)
aquamarine2=(118,238,198)
```

It works out and provides variables with colors, but I would love to have more variety and an easier and cleaner way to access this. Online, I have only found ways to find specific colors, but nothing in bulk and in format to copy and paste.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic.  Please read the following documentation, then edit and rephrase the question.  [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Reading the documentation (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html) helps: there is a module `pygame.colordict` that contains a `dict` with all supported name strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see all the colors by looking at the dict **pygame.color.THECOLORS**. However that dict of all the names and color values is large (657 when I am writing this) and so it can be cumbersome to look through and find what you want.

I often find myself trying to find color names and find this snippet very handy:

```
import pygame
from pprint import  pprint

color_list = [(c, v) for c, v in pygame.color.THECOLORS.items() if 'slategrey' in c]
pprint(color_list)
```

which outputs:

```
[('darkslategrey', (47, 79, 79, 255)),
 ('slategrey', (112, 128, 144, 255))
 ('lightslategrey', (119, 136, 153, 255))]
```

I do that in an interactive session to get all the names that include 'slategrey' and then in my actual code I can use the one I want like this:

```
slategrey = pygame.Color("slategrey")
```

and then later in the code reference it like this:

```
screen.fill(slategrey,  pygame.Rect(0, 0, 100, 100))
```

However, if you really want to see the list of all the colors in pygame.color.THECOLORS, you can look at them here in pygames [colordict module](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/master/src_py/colordict.py) where THECOLORS is defined.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas Kläger already noted in a comment, there's a list of possible color strings in pygame.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/master/src_py/colordict.py) to see all those strings and their RGB value.

If you want, you can access this dict via  `pygame.color.THECOLORS`, but you usually don't need to. You can just pass a string with the color name to pygame's `Color` class, like this:

```
screen.fill(pygame.Color('red'),  pygame.Rect(  0, 0, 100, 100))
screen.fill(pygame.Color('plum'), pygame.Rect(100, 0, 100, 100))
screen.fill(pygame.Color('pink'), pygame.Rect(100, 0, 100, 100))
```

Of course there's no list of *every* possible color, since there are 256^3 = 16.777.216 possible colors in pygame (4.294.967.296 if you include different alpha values).