# Pygame reading a string off a .txt file and then using as a color error

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a background drawing system for a game using pygame, and as there are 1024 seperate squares per scene, I'm storing the color attached to each square in a .txt file, like

```
square1 = BLACK
square2 = GREEN
```

and so on.

When I read my file using this code

```
    read = open("testgraphics.txt", "r")
    xcoords = 0
    ycoords = 0
    for x in read:
        if xcoords > 1024:
            xcoords += 32
        else:
            ycoords += 32
        print(x)
        squarecolorformatting = x[-6:]
        squarecolor = squarecolorformatting[:-1]
        print(squarecolor) #This returns a string of just the color I want, e.g. BLACK
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,squarecolor, [xcoords,ycoords,32,32])
    #print(f.read())
    Scene1Read = True
    read.close()
```

I get the error `TypeError: invalid color argument` for the pygame.draw line. I understand
that I've read a string from my file, but how do I let python know I want my string "BLACK" to apply to the colors I set at start of my program, when I did `BLACK = (0, 0, 0)`?

Comment: You use a dictionary, e.g., {'BLACK': (0,0,0), 'WHITE': (255,255,244)}

Comment: @JustinEzequiel does the pygame drawer allow color rgb values as a list instead of a color name then?

Comment: What list? The dictionary is to look up the color value from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in a previous answer here how to investigate the colors in **pygame.color.THECOLORS** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795570/is-there-a-file-with-every-color-on-python/61151251#61151251).

So if you have a string that names a color in pygames predefined colors you can grab the colors themselves like this:

```py
BLACK = pygame.Color("black")
GREEN = pygame.Color("green")
```

Note that the names of the colors are lower case.

Answer (score 1):

*I have no experience with pygame, BUT*:

Little advice:

Use JSON. With JSON you can simply read lists and dictionaries from files and write them to files.

JSON is a standard library, so you don't have to install it.

JSONfile

```
{"square1" : "BLACK", "square2" : "GREEN"}
```

Pythonfile

```
import json
```

For reading:

```
with open("MYFILE.json", "r") as file:
    mydata = json.load(file)

squarecolor = mydata["square1"]
```

For writing:

```
with open("MYFILE.json", "w+") as file: 
    #The + behind the w means, that, if the file doesn't exist, python creates it
    json.dump(mydata, file)
```

Comment: But would this allow me to render all 1024 squares in 10 lines of code? Your method seems to imply I'd have to type out all the keys

Comment: If you mean the looping you can just use this: ```for i in range(len(mydata)): squarecolor = mydata["square" + i] ```